# Apache Kylin: sql query error ： java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: kylin

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.kylin.jdbc.KylinMeta.prepareAndExecute
(Lorg/apache/calcite/avatica/Meta$ConnectionHandle;Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/calcite/avatica/Meta$PrepareCallback;)Lorg/apache/calcite/avatica/Meta$ExecuteResult;
org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:474)

Comment: You're just showing us an error... What are you trying to do, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I use url jdbc:kylin://.../mydb to access remote db.

Comment: this.kylinJdbcTemplate.queryForList("select  * from table limit 1"); this is the sql statement for the query.

Comment: Then I run the example from kylin website, also has the same error above.

Answer (score 0):

this error is only at kylin-jdbc-1.5.2.jar. When I use kylin-jdbc-2.1.0.jar, the above issue was settled.